# xpath the parent having all of its child element names as same

Tags: xml, xpath, orbeon

How can i select parent nodes for which all of its child element node names are same. In the below example, parent node `<a id="1">` should be selected since all the child node names are `b`

```
<form>
  <a id="1">
    <b>1</b>
    <b>2</b>
    <b>3</b>
  </a>
  <a id="2">
    <b>1</b>
    <c>2</c>
    <b>3</b>
  </a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I. XPath 1.0**:

**Use**:

```
/*/*
   [not(*[position() > 1
      and
          not(name()= name(../*[1]))
         ]
        )
    ]
```

This selects any child element of the top element, such that the name of any child element with `position()` greater than one, is equal to the name of the first child of that element.

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the **[Double-Negation law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation)**.

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "/*/*
        [not(*[position() > 1
             and
               not(name()= name(../*[1]))
               ]
            )
       ]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<form>
    <a id="1">
        <b>1</b>
        <b>2</b>
        <b>3</b>
    </a>
    <a id="2">
        <b>1</b>
        <c>2</c>
        <b>3</b>
    </a>
</form>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the selected elements (in this case just one) are copied to the output**:

```
<a id="1">
   <b>1</b>
   <b>2</b>
   <b>3</b>
</a>
```

---

**II. XPath 2.0**:

```
/*/*[every $vChild in * satisfies name($vChild) eq $vChild/../*[1]/name()]
```

Comment: is $vChikd a variable referring to `//a/*` nodesets

Comment: @KaipaMSarma, `$vChild` "iterates" over any child element of any `/*/*` element (which in the case of the provided XML document is: any child element of any `a` element)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following XPath expression:

```
//*[./* and not(./*[name() != name(../*[1])])]
```

It selects any element that has children, but the name of none of them is different from the first child's name.

It returns `form` as well, because all its children are named `a`.